# Reinforce screw holes

Tags: fusion360

I made some 3D printed supports for tools, using screws to fix it to the wall, some of them broken because of the screw forces. Is there a way to reinforce only the screw holes where it will have more stress/compress? I am using PLA, Fusion 360 and Ultimaker Cura.

Comment: you might want to look at the slicing too

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! I'm not completely understanding what you are trying to reinforce? Are they just holes which the screw goes through? Or are they actual threads you are printing which you need to reinforce? Could you provide a picture of the area you are working with?

Comment: This question is not very clear, are you interested in local increase of the infill (see e.g. [this question](/q/6522/)), dimensional hole accuracy or techniques to design support fixtures/lugs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oscar, the e.g. you shared here is exactly what I need. I think you understand the question very well. Cheers.

Comment: Looking at the answers, you are after local strengthening, this can be done by changing the infill percentage around holes and is described in [this question](/q/6522/); this could imply that this is a duplicate.

Comment: Are you using screws similar to drywall screws which have a flat head that tapers down to the screw or a pan head screw which usually has a rounded head and flat bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test different print settings. Trying to visualize, but I believe you can increase the **perimeter lines**, since there is a hole, this will increase the resistance in that area. Or try to change the **orientation** with which the part will be printed

Comment: Hello thanks for your input, I am trying to find how to increase the perimeter line in Fusion360, where is it? :)

Comment: @Manolo These settings are made inside the CURA (**shell settings**)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a washer between the screw head and the plastic material to distribute the load

In my designs I also put in a depression to fit the washer so that it sits flush with the resultant surface.

[image: Cad design with recessed washer holes]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is a good idea, I will try to do that as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add localised extra walls, I will sometimes *cut* a torus shape around the part that I want to strengthen. This can result in n*wall, infill, n*wall, void, n*wall.

See the images in this [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/7022/4927) if the description is not clear.